# Quick questions on importing data using datagrab

Tags: datagrab, number-format

I'm going to be importing some info using DataGrab for about 700 entries (on this site an entry is a construction project). One of the fields is a number that shows the cost of the project. On the front end of the site users need to be able to order the projects based on the cost. I want to display the cost on the front end with commas where necessary ($1,123,345). What is the best way to setup the import for that field? If it's a text field would I be able to order if it has numbers and commas? If it is a numbers field would I be able to add commas after the fact? I just don't want the client to have to go back and redo the projects import file. Any ideas would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would setup the field as a text input field and set the field content to `number` –this way sorting on the front end can work properly (ie. sort highest to lowest, etc.). Remove all currency characters & thousands separators on the numbers before importing.

Re: formatting, you can use [several different number format addons](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=number%20format&addon_version_support=ee2) to achieve the thousands separator.

Comment: Thanks Siebird, I figured I would have to remove the currency and comma characters. I found this plugin http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dollars-fieldtype...I assume that will only work for numbers added to the field in the publish form and not when imported using DataGrab into the field...any thoughts on that?

Comment: Just took a quick look, it looks likes it stores the values in `int` format–so all data will have to be in that format before importing w/DataGrab. This addon makes it user-friendly for the client in the CP. He recommends a addon or php to do the proper formatting like I mentioned above.